# How to get numpy array from scipy LinearOperator?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a LinearOperator constructed in some program package. I want to compute an iLU preconditioner and to use it in scipy solver.
Problem is the type of input object for preconditioner calculating. If you want to use "spilu" function you should use numpy array in input, but I have a LinearOperator!
Therefore, how can I transform LinearOperator to numpy array? Or is other way to compute iLU preconditioner exists?

Comment: Is this the LO, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html

Comment: You may need to add a small concrete example.

Comment: *"I have a LinearOperator constructed in some program package."* Which package?  What more do you know about the `LinearOperator` that you have?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can get the matrix associated with the `LinearOperator` is to multiply it by the identity matrix.

In this example, `op` is a `LinearOperator` with shape (3, 3):

```
In [103]: op
Out[103]: <3x3 MyOperator with dtype=int64>
```

Here's the actual matrix associated with `op`:

```
In [104]: op * np.eye(op.shape[1], dtype=op.dtype)
Out[104]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 6, 7]])
```

Warning!  `np.eye()` creates a *dense* array, and the above multiplication returns a *dense* numpy array.  If the shape of your `LinearOperator` is too big, you may run out of memory.

Going from a `LinearOperator` to a *sparse* matrix without generating an intermediate dense array is probably possible, but will require a bit more code.  Before spending too much time on that, check the attributes and methods of the specific `LinearOperator` that you have.  It may have internal data that is already in a sparse format.